# T-SQL Background Processing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having the trouble finding the wording, but is it possible to provide a SQL query to a MS SQL server and retrieve the results asynchronously?

I'd like to submit the query from a web request, but I'd like the web process to terminate while the SQL server continues processing the query and dumps the results into a temp table that I can retrieve later.

Or is there some common modifier I can append to the query to cause it to background process the results (like "&" in bash).

More info

I manage a site that allows trusted users to run arbitrary select queries on very large data sets.  I'm currently using a Java Daemon to examine a "jobs" table and run the results, I was just hopeful that there might be a more native solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on how you are communicating with the DB. With ADO.NET you can make a command execution run asynchronously. If you were looking to do this outside the scope of some library built to do it you could insert a record into a job table and then have SQL Agent poll the table and then run your work as a stored procedure or something.

In all likelihood though I would guess your web request is received by asp.net and you could use the ADO.NET classes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your clarification, I think you might consider a derived OLAP database that's designed for those types of queries. Since they seem to be strategic to the business.

Answer (score 0):

See this question
[Start stored procedures sequentially or in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349951/start-stored-procedures-sequentially-or-in-parallel#349987)

In effect, you would have the web page start a job.  The job would execute asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Since http is connectionless, the only way to associate the retrieval with the query would be with sessions. THen you'd have all these answers waiting around for someone to claim them, and no way to know if the connection (that doesn't exist) has been broken.

In a web page, it's pretty much use-it-or-lose-it.

Some of the other answers might work with a lot of effort, but I don't get the sense that you're looking for an edge-case, high-tech option.

Answer (score -1):

It's a complicated topic to be able to execute a stored procedure and then asynchronously retrieve the result. It's not really for the faint of heart and my first recommendation would be to reexamine your design and be certain that you in fact need to asynchronously process your request in the data tier.

Depending on what precisely you are doing you should look at 2 technologies... SQL Service Broker which basically allows you to queue requests and receive responses asyncrhonously. It was introduced in SQL 2005 and sounds like it may be the best bet from the way you phrased your question.

Take a look at the tutorial for same database service broker conversations on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839495(SQL.90).aspx

For longer running or larger processing tasks I'd potentially look at something like Biztalk or Windows Workflow. These frameworks (they're largely the same, they came from the same team at MS) allow you to start an asynchronous workflow that may not return for hours, days, weeks, or even months.